# Trying to get Eclipse Workspace available project list, but IWorkspace not working because its not plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

Unable to get Workspace location in eclipse (list of project available in workspace).
IWorkspace not working because of not a plugin application.

Please suggest the way to get list of all project available in eclipse workspace

Comment: You have already answered the question yourself. What prevents you from doing this in an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: I am looking for the way to get this kind of functionality in plain core java project where i can get the list of available project in workspace

Comment: Why do you want to limit yourself to a plain Java application? That does not sound clever. For each project a folder can be found in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects`.

Comment: You can't do this in a plain Java application. You could use a  'headless' Eclipse RCP.